# update array smarty

Tags: smarty

in smarty i have this array:

```
{$user}
Array (3)
0 => Array (2)
  id => "1"
  name => "Peter"
1 => Array (2)
  id => "2"
  name => "Joy"
2 => Array (2)
  id => "3"
  name => "Sandra"
```

How i can update this array(with php)?
Insert new element, age:

```
Array (3)
0 => Array (2)
  id => "1"
  name => "Peter"
  age => "16"
1 => Array (2)
  id => "2"
  name => "Joy"
  age => "17"
2 => Array (2)
  id => "3"
  name => "Sandra"
  age => "20"
```

Comment: Smarty - Template Engine:
http://www.smarty.net/

Answer (score 2):

I would define the array in PHP.
And then use $smarty->assign() to publish it to the smarty template.